# Changes are not saved to the database

Tags: hsqldb

I have a database testdb. Once I filled it with data through a program hsqldb Manager. Then I tried to do the same thing only with code. In this case, the insert command adds a new record, but after the update, the record disappears. What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to report your code for inserting into the database. At the end of your program, you need to execute the SQL to SHUTDOWN the database.